# operator delete standard behavior

Tags: c++

I can't understand what standard need to do with calling operator delete for void* == nullptr.

Something like this:

```
void foo(void* ptr) // ptr == nullptr here
{
    delete ptr;
}
```

On the one hand, we have the following statement in standard:

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

5.3.5 Delete [expr.delete]

> 1 ... The operand shall have a pointer to object type, or a class type
>   having a single non-explicit conversion function (12.3.2) to a pointer
>   to object type. The result has type void.78
>
> 78) **This implies that an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of
>   type void* because void is not an object type**.

which makes code with deleting void* ill-formed. On the other hand, we have another statement about nullptr in delete:

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

5.3.5 Delete [expr.delete]

> 2 ... In the first alternative (delete object), **the value of the
>   operand of delete may be a null pointer value**, a pointer to a
>   non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to
>   a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause
>   10). If not, the behavior is undefined. In the second alternative
>   (delete array), **the value of the operand of delete may be a null
>   pointer value** or a pointer value that resulted from a previous array
>   new-expression.79 If not, the behavior is undefined.

What implementation need to do in such kind of situation?

Comment: And where is the contradiction ? You can delete `NULL` or non-`void *` stuff.

Comment: @cnicutar i've added an example to my question

Comment: The type of `nullptr` is not `void*`, it's `std::nullptr_t`, and it is implicitly convertible to any pointer type. This is far from being `void*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Null and `void*` are two different things:

```
delete static_cast<int*>(nullptr); // deleting null pointer, of int*
```

Your given code would be ill-formed, but it has nothing to do with the *value* of the pointer (which may be null), but its *type* (which cannot be `void*`).

Comment: See an example in my question

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Seen. I don't see where the contradiction is. Those are two separate clauses for a reason, the first explicitly talks about `void*` while the second refers to `delete` in general.

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: `void *` is the pointer *type*. While `NULL` is the *value* of the pointer. There is a difference. Simply put, It is allowed to have a pointer with value `NULL` provided that pointer is not of the *type* `void *`.